# Degree of a retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am wondering about how to compute the degree of $r(z) := \frac{z}{| z |}$.
I know that $deg f_n = n$ where $f_n (z)= z^n$ i.e. the degree is how many times it goes around $0$. I also know that $deg(f \circ g) = deg (f) \cdot deg (g)$. Now with $f(z)=z$, $deg f = 1$, but what about $f(z) = \frac{z}{|z|}$?

**Edit:**

Where $r: \mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \} \rightarrow S^1$.
The degree is defined for continuous functions $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$.
$ \mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ so I was thinking $r$ can be viewed as function $r: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$. I'm asking this question because I think $deg (r)$ is used in a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that degree is defined for everything? Ok, what is then the degree of $\sin$ or $\arcsin$?

Comment: What is $z$? Please define your function $r$ properly; what is its domain and codomain?

Comment: As i know the dgree of a map is defined for maps from $S^1\to S^1$ and at your case $f(z)=z$ has degree 1.

Comment: @omar: no, I'm interested in the case $f(z) = \frac{z}{|z|}$.

Comment: $f(z) = z/|z| = z$ since any point on the circle has absolute valu 1. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not missing anything! Thank you! Maybe you could post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $r:\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\to S^1$ is itself a (/ the standard) homotopy equivalence, with homotopy inverse just the inclusion. So if you want to view $r$ as function $S^1\to S^1$ via the standard homotopy equivalence, i.e. $S^1\to \mathbb{C}-\{0\}\to S^1$, then this is homotopic equivalent to the identity map, which has degree 1!

Edit, in reply to your comment:

I don't know what $deg(r)$ means. You said you wanted to view $r$ as a map $S^1\to S^1$ using the homotopy equivalence of $S^1$ and $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. I can only *interpret* this to mean that instead of $r$ we consider $r\circ i$. Or, if you will, we define $\deg(r):=\deg(r\circ i)$. Now the latter has degree 1 because $r\circ i$ is homotopic to the identity map on $S^1$.

Comment: Thank you!! Let me repeat to see if I understand correctly: $deg (i) = 1$ because the inclusion is the identity. $deg (i \circ r) = deg (r \circ i) = 1$ because both are homotopic to the identity functions (respectively). Therefore $deg (i \circ r) = deg(r) deg(i) = deg(r) \cdot 1 = 1$ implies $deg(r) = 1$.

Comment: I think I have to add '@....' in order to appear in your inbox.

Comment: No, it reached my inbox :)

Comment: Oh well : ) Ok, I assume no comment means yes what I repeated is what you meant. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @last comment: no, I edited my answer!

Comment: hm... no, I actually meant $r: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$. Why consider $r \circ i$ instead of $r$? If $r: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ there has to be a way to find $deg(r)$.

Comment: ? $r$ is a map $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\to S^1$. It is not a map $S^1\to S^1$. $r\circ i$ *is* a map $S^1\to S^1$.